Decomposition of curvatures and the eigenvector of curvature operator
$\newcommand\KN{\bigcirc
\kern-2.5ex\wedge \;}$
For hypersurfaces, Gauss equation implies that the curvature tensor can be expressed by second fundamental form $\text{II}$: $R$ is just $\text{II}\otimes \text{II}$ then restrict on $\wedge^2(TM)$, in terms of Kulkarni–Nomizu product, this is $R=\text{II}{\KN}\text{II}$. This in particular leads to the fact that if an orthonormal basis $E_i$ diagonalizes $\text{II}$, $E_i\wedge E_j$ also diagonalizes $\mathfrak R$, that is, eigenvectors of $\mathfrak R$ can be expressed by decompoable bivectors $E_i\wedge E_j$, this is true for any decoposable $R=h\KN h$ for some symmetric $h$. I'm wondering how much restrictions  this puts on manifolds that can be emdeded in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.
Clearly this is not true for general symmetric tensors on $\wedge^2TM$, since you can define a symmetric tensor on a space by select an orthonormal basis as eigenvectors, and they need not to be pure decomposable ones like $E_i\wedge E_j$. Now we take Bianchi identity into account, namely, wse consider algebraic curvature tensor $\mathcal R(V^*)$ for some vector space $V$, then I think $R$ also doesn't always have a decomposition $R=h\KN k$ for some symmetric 2-tensor $h,k$ but I am not sure how to do this(this looks similar to tensor products) How do we describe decomposable ones, namely, how to describe $$\KN:(\text{sym}^2V)^2\to \mathcal R(V^*)$$?
Now we turn to the manifold case, note every algebraic curvature can be realized at a point as some Riemannian curvature, so if there are counterexamples that such decomposition and eigenvectors not exists, we can exhibit many $n$-manifolds that cannot not embedded isometricly in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, what is an easy example in low dimension?

Your question and more are answered in a paper by Berger, Bryant, Griffiths. I like your question asking for an easy example. They prove that hyperbolic $3$-space cannot be locally isometrically embedded into Euclidean $4$-space. https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-50/issue-3/The-Gauss-equations-and-rigidity-of-isometric-embeddings/10.1215/S0012-7094-83-05039-1.short

@Deane thanks for reference! The hyperbolic space is a space form so i think it’s curvature has a desired composition by metric, so it’s not an example that im looking for.

You should look into hyperbolic space a bit more carefully. It isn't even easy (even though it is possible)  to find local isometric embeddings of hyperbolic 2-space into Euclidean 3-space. Hilbert's theorem says it's not possible globally. And B-B-G really do prove it's impossible, even locally, in higher dimensions.

It is not possible to embed into euclidean space, but not because its curvature cannot be decomposed as KN product of bilinear forms. Here I want some simple example of curvature that cannot decomposed in KN product, so that we can easily see it cannot embed

The proof that hyperbolic $n$-space cannot be locally isometrically embedded into Euclidean $(n+1)$-space is stated and proved in BBG on page 860. As far as I can tell, the proof shows that there does not exist a solution to the Gauss equations. In other words, there is no way to represent the hyperbolic curvature tensor as the KN product of a bilinear form with itself.

Actually, the proof that there is no symmetric tensor whose KN product with itself is equal to the hyperbolic curvature tensor in dimension 3 is relatively easy to prove. The sectional curvatures are the products of pairs of principal curvatures. It's not possible for all three products to be negative.

thank you Sir! I see, and they actually proved something stronger!

@Deane, but why Hilbert’s proof hyperbolic plane cannot embed in $R^3$ is much more complicated than this argument?

You can do an initial assessment by comparing the dimensions of the space of curvature tensors versus the space of symmetric tensors. In dimensions 4 and higher, the first is $n^2(n^2-1)/12$, which is bigger than $n(n+1)/2$. So it makes it less likely that the Gauss equations have a solution. In dimension 3, the dimensions are equal, so there is at least a chance. However, as I observed, this is easily analyzed. And the proof applies to higher dimensions, too. In dimension 2, the first dimension is 1 and the second is 3. Since it's just $\det(\operatorname{II}) = K$, there are many solutions.

You can also verify that there are solutions to the Codazzi-Mainardi equations. So this type of analysis of the situation provides no barriers to the existence of an isometric embedding of hyperbolic 2-space in Euclidean 3-space. In fact, the PDE turns out to get a hyperbolic PDE that has local solutions. The proof of Hilbert theorem therefore requires a careful analysis of a global solution and cannot be proved using only pointwise multilinear algebra.
